# confluent jdbc-source-connector not working from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect

I have a jdbc-source-connector working when I run it from command line as below

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh \
    config/connect-standalone.properties \
    config/connect_mysql-jdbc-source.properties
```

but when I parse the file content into a map in a Java application and create an instance of
`io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector` with the map as argument I get

> `java.sql.SQLException:` Access denied for user `''@'localhost'` (using
> password: `NO`)

Below is the content of my connector that, as I said, works when invoked from the command line and creates all the 3 topics

```
   name=test-mysql-jdbc   
   connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
   tasks.max=1
   connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/loaderDB 
   connection.user=root
   connection.password=MyPassword
   table.whitelist=loader_jobs, education_event, school_unit   
   tables="loader_jobs, education_event, school_unit"
   mode=bulk
   topic.prefix=test_mysql_jdbc_ 
   numeric.mapping=best_fit   
   poll.interval.ms=86400000 
   batch.max.rows=10000
```

When debugging the application I can clearly see that the all the properties are read and when it gets to the part to assign the connection url to get the database connection it throws the SQL exception above.

There is nowhere in that class any mention about the database user and password, so I tried changing the `connection.url` in the config file to

```
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/loaderDB?user=root&password=MyPassword
```

but still I got the same Exception

Comment: Doesn't look like a connect problem. You must allow database access.... Nowhere about user and password? I clearly see two connection properties that use that

Comment: First OneCricketeer, I am not sure that you red the whole post.As I mentioned in the post I use the same connector file from the command line without any problems. So where should I allow dB access? The properties you see are the ones in the connector file, what I said was when I debug the application and get into confluents JdbcSourceConnector class I did not see any properties forDB user and password, it only has a URL property.

Comment: Each line from the file is passed into a `Properties` object in code. So I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Connect is meant to be ran via the CLI, not embedded in another process

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by upgrading my pom dependency as follow

```
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-connect-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
```

I was using version 2.0.1 earlier.